# SQL: Select top 1 of each group returning multiple records for each group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which looks like this:

```
| Id | InvestorFundId | Name | AccountKey | AsOfDate | AddedOn  |
| 1  | 11111          | Name1| Key1       | 9/5/2018 | 8/5/2018 |
| 2  | 11111          | Name2| Key1       | 9/3/2018 | 8/5/2018 |
| 3  | 22222          | Name3| Key2       | 9/2/2018 | 8/5/2018 |
| 4  | 33333          | Name4| Key3       | 9/2/2018 | 8/5/2018 |
| 5  | 33333          | Name5| Key3       | 9/4/2018 | 8/5/2018 |
```

I need to be able to return the most recent `InvestorFundId`, Name, and `AccountKey` for each group, based on ordered `AsOfDate` and `AddedOn` descending.

Expected result should look like this:

```
| InvestorFundId | Name | AccountKey |
| 11111          | Name1| Key1       | 
| 22222          | Name3| Key2       |
| 33333          | Name5| Key3       |
```

I've looked at some posts but I can't correctly return the rows, here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT Name, AccountKey, H.InvestorFundId FROM
[Investor.Fund.History] H
CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 InvestorFundId 
FROM [Investor.Fund.History] 
WHERE  DataStatusId = 1 AND AsOfYearMonth <= 201806
ORDER BY AsOfDate DESC, AddedOn DESC) HS
ORDER BY H.InvestorFundId
```

But this is returning me multiple records for each group instead of the most recent.

I just want to add that the current implementation uses ROW_NUMBER but it is too slow, so I am investigating into other solutions.

Thank you

NOTE: I know that I have two extra columns in my where, I just opted to exclude those from the diagram but you should be able to get the gist

Comment: Sorry that row_number is too slow, but thats going to be the correct answer every time for this problem. Certainly should be faster than your cross apply query, Can you post the row_number query as there may just be something wrong. Other than that it might be improved with the correct indexes.

Comment: My thought exactly @TomC

Answer (score 3):

You can use a CTE to get the data you need.

```
USE tempdb;
GO

DECLARE @table TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1), InvestorFundId INT, Name VARCHAR(50), AccountKey VARCHAR(50), AsOfDate DATE, AddedOn DATE);
INSERT INTO @table VALUES (11111, 'Name1', 'Key1', '9/5/2018', '8/5/2018');
INSERT INTO @table VALUES (11111, 'Name2', 'Key1', '9/3/2018', '8/5/2018');
INSERT INTO @table VALUES (22222, 'Name3', 'Key2', '9/2/2018', '8/5/2018');
INSERT INTO @table VALUES (33333, 'Name4', 'Key3', '9/2/2018', '8/5/2018');
INSERT INTO @table VALUES (33333, 'Name5', 'Key3', '9/4/2018', '8/5/2018');

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT InvestorFundId, Name, AccountKey, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY InvestorFundID ORDER BY AsOfDate DESC) AS RowId FROM @table
)
SELECT InvestorFundId, Name, AccountKey
    FROM CTE
    WHERE RowId = 1;
```

Here is a working [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f864f/1/0)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WITH TIES` and simply apply `ROW_NUMBER` in the `ORDER BY`

```
Select top 1 with ties *
From History
Where DataStatusId = 1 and AsOfYearMonth = 201806
Order by 
Row_Number() over (partition by InvestorFundID order by AsOfDate desc)
```

Or with a sub query

```
Select  *
    From (select * , RN= Row_Number() over (partition by InvestorFundID order by AsOfDate desc)
             From History
             Where DataStatusId = 1 and AsOfYearMonth = 201806) x
Where x.RN = 1
```

If you find this slower, then we’d need to see the execution plan to determine WHY it’s slow. A non-clustered index on InvestorFundId, AsOfDate desc would make this super fast.

```
Create nonclustered index indexName on
History (InvestorFundID, AsOfDate desc)
```

Comment: Good alternative although quick test shows this as significantly slower than the CTE version, with or without the index.

Comment: I’d have to test but I’d still use a sub query over a CTE. Added that version

Comment: Why is that? The CTE in this case will evaluate to exactly the same execution plan as a nested subquery. Just IMO a neater query. Probably one of those things that is down to a personal preference though.

Comment: Because in non complex queries a CTE can produce results that you wouldn’t expect. A bit off topic for this question but a common scenario is filtering on a single predicate, say where column = 1 and column is varchar, in the CTE and then converting this column in the follow on select. You can get a conversion error when you shouldn’t since the CTE should “filter” this. There are a few examples of this though it’s rare and only seen in simple CTE queries.